# Why in Cassandra doesn't support conditional updates on counter tables?

Tags: cassandra

Can't understand why. It looks natural to increment/decrement (especially to decrement!) row's counter only if row already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **counter increments/decrements are not idempotent**.

With LightWeight Transaction (using Paxos underneath), *a failed Paxos commit will be replayed by the next Paxos round*. This guarantees that Paxos operations are linearizable.

If the mutation is not idempotent, it breaks completely this mechanism so the guarantee is lost.

Comment: Is it supported now ?